# Date and Time Information from Wi-Fi Router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I am trying to get the current date and time from a Wi-Fi router. All I can find is that Cisco IOS-based routers can provide a mechanism where the router can be configured as an NTP server.

I have tried other routers like a Netgear N300 and a ZHONE-TECH. These routers do not provide a way to configure an NTP service.

Comment: What model of router is it? Do you want to get time information or configure your router as a ntp server? Do you have access to a gui or cli?

Comment: I would like to get current date and time from router. One of the way i have found is by configuring router as NTP server. Is there any other way to do the same?

Comment: By the way, "timing information" usually means measurement of how long something takes, not the current time of day. I've edited your question to say what you really meant.

Comment: Really sorry for not putting my query correctly and thanks @Spiff for editing the question.

Comment: I have found a mechanism in which Instead of sending NTP packets to remote time server the date and the time can also be extracted from any HTTP header returned after an HTTP GET request. But this requires internet connection again is there any other way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your network device(s) to get the time from your router, then ntp is what you need. Connect through http(s) to your router to configure this. If you would like to do it through cli (IOS) then there are multiple sites explaining how to do this. Like here: [Setting up NTP on Cisco iOS Devices](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/122464-setting-up-ntp-on-cisco-ios-devices)

Comment: Netgear N300 and ZHONE-TECH 6518-A1-EU do not have NTP server configuration. Is there any other way to get the timing information.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your first post. Buy a router who can run ntp services or manually change the ntp settings on the host that is requesting the time to a public ntp server.